# scrapping with Goutte\Client in many page

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, web-scraping

I´m building a scrapping script to verifry any data in this web. My script should visit this web and get all `hrefs`. In this step i haven´t got any problem.

In my next step i verify that my data in db it´s same that scrapper return. First i´m clearing all my data and reorder my array. Next i´m building a loop from all lenght of this array. Now i´m doing a new loop and now i´m checking that data in first array it´s same in second loop. It´s same, i´m building a new array with the data find, and if i´m not find anything, i´m building a new array with not find data. In one or the other i´m doing `unset()` to eliminate this index and also i´m doing a new `array_slice` to order index after removal. After, i´m doing a while to call my function again send it my array with a minus index. In this while i´m building a associative array with all my `result_ok` and `result_ko`

My problem it´s that always my server (in localhost, in this moment) arrive to timeout and i don´t know how i can to solve this.

In my code i have a `break` to get out of the loop, but delay very much.

My logic it´s:

```
$counter = 0;

        try{
            foreach($data as $content){
                $file_headers = @get_headers($content["post_url"]);
                if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
                    $exists = false;
                    $access_ko[] = $this->order;
                }else{
                    $client = new Client();
                    $website = $client->request('GET', $content["post_url"]);
                    $website->filter('p > a')->each(function ($node) {
                        // adding data into array with all link found
                        array_push($this->found_link, $node->text());
                        array_push($this->hrefs, $node->attr('href'));
                        array_push($this->rels, $node->attr('href'));

                    });// END EACH FUNCTION

                }// end else

                break;
            }// end initial foreach
            
            // delete empty index and order array.
            $order_array = array_filter($this->found_link); 
            $clear_array = array_slice($order_array, 0);

            // loop to compare all data
            for($i=1; $i<count($clear_array); $i++){
                // loop to compare node->text with data
                foreach($data as $result){
                    if($clear_array[$i] == $data[$i]["anchor_text"]){
                        //if condition it´s true assign data to array, that will be returned to view or PDF
                        $finalData = [
                            'pedido' => $data[$i]["order"],
                            'articulo'  => $data[$i]["order_name"],
                            'url' => $data[$i]["url"],
                            'post_url' => $data[$i]["post_url"],
                            'anchor_text' => $data[$i]["anchor_text"],
                            'tipo'  => $data[$i]["type_link"],
                            // scraping web result
                            'result_test' => $this->hrefs[$i],
                            'link_rel'  => $this->rels[$i],
                        ];
                        array_push($this->result_ok, $finalData);
                        unset($this->found_link[$i]);
                        $this->newArray = array_slice($this->found_link, 0);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        $finalData = [
                            'pedido' => $data[$i]["order"],
                            'articulo'  => $data[$i]["order_name"],
                            'url' => $data[$i]["url"],
                            'post_url' => $data[$i]["post_url"],
                            'anchor_text' => $data[$i]["anchor_text"],
                            'tipo'  => $data[$i]["type_link"],
                            // scraping web result
                            'result_test' => $this->hrefs[$i],
                            'link_rel'  => $this->rels[$i],
                        ];
                        $this->result_ko[] = $finalData; 
                        array_push($this->result_ko, $finalData);
                        unset($this->found_link[$i]);
                        $this->newArray = array_slice($this->found_link, 0);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                $counter++;

            }// end for

            /*var_dump($this->result_ok);
            exit();*/

            while($counter <= 1){
                $this->checkPages($data);
                return array("result_ok" => $this->result_ok, "result_ko" => $this->result_ko);
            }
            
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            Log::info('have a error or warning in function checkPages in controller CheckPublicationsClientController with this message: '. $e->getMessage());
            echo "entro exception: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
```

one example data:

```
/**
         *   EXAMPLE DATA THAT ARRIVE TO THIS FUNCTION
         * 
         *   "order" => "PEDIDO#20002 - mundoejecutivo.com.mx"
         *   "order_name" => "mundoejecutivo.com.mx"
         *   "post_url" => "https://mundoejecutivo.com.mx/empresas/empleos-mas-demandados-en-mexico-y-un-enfoque-a-especialistas-en-sap/"
         *   "anchor_text" => "Xamai es partner SAP"
         *   "url" => "https://mx.xamai.com/"
         *   "type_link" => "follow"
         */
```

In `post_url` i´m searching all `ahrefs` and if contain `["anchor_text"]` i´m doing my `for and foreach`

I hope that anybody can help me to optimice this code or todo with better solution. Now i have 300 order to check, but it´s very possible that this number increment.

**Update**

now i´m trying to create queue to solve my problem. I did a `php artisan make:job CheckPages` and in my function handle only i have my logic to check if link exists and extract info from url:

```
public function __construct($dataReceived)
    {
        $this->data = $dataReceived;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try{
            DB::commit();
            for($i=1; $i<count($this->data); $i++){
                $file_headers = @get_headers($this->data[$i]["post_url"]);
                if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
                    $exists = false;
                    $access_ko[] = $this->data[$i]["order"];
                    break;
                }else{
                    $client = new Client();
                    $website = $client->request('GET', $this->data[$i]["post_url"]);
                    $website->filter('p > a')->each(function ($node) {
                        // adding data into array with all link found
                        array_push($this->found_link, $node->text());
                        array_push($this->hrefs, $node->attr('href'));
                        array_push($this->rels, $node->attr('href'));

                    });// END EACH FUNCTION

                    break;

                }// end else
            }
            return array("found_link" => $this->found_link, 'hrefs' => $this->hrefs, 'rels' => $this->rels);
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
            Log::info('have a error or warning in function checkPages in controller CheckPublicationsClientController with this message: '. $e->getMessage());
            echo "entro exception: ".$e->getMessage();
        }              
    }
```

I´m calling this queue in my controller:

```
$result = CheckPages::dispatch($newAllDataOrder);
```

but now i don´t know what should I do?

Thanks you for readme and help me

Comment: Sounds like you should either use a larger timeout, or put the scraping parts into a queue and run that through CLI

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for your comment, this timeout, i should increase it in my localhost or in my code? i sill search that i can do with queue

Comment: Using a larger timeout will only be a temporary fix. If you already plan to use a queue, go that way

Comment: Pet peeve: the word you are looking for is ["to scrape"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrape), present participle "scraping", past "scraped". If you were to ["scrap"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrap) a website ("scrapping", "scrapped") you would be throwing it away, not extracting anything from it.

Comment: @scorpions77 I'm just pointing out a (surprisingly common) spelling mistake: you have repeatedly referred to your script as "scrapping" the website, but that would mean something very different from "scraping" it.

Comment: @IMSoP ah ok, i´m sorry for my mistake

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for your response. but i don´t understand very well how i can to work with queue  because i need after, return results and in function handle i can´t return result

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it, not to the comment section.

Comment: @NicoHaase i update my question, with my queue, but i´m blocked i don´t know very well what should I do because i can´t access to my queue result